# what do you mean by (a&1) in c++?

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

In some c++ code I have seen that someone using a statement like

```
while(a) { //here a is an integer variable
    if(a&1) {
        //some expression
    }
}
```

now my question is what is the meaning of `a&1` ?

Comment: It's [bitwise AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND).

Answer (score 4):

It checks if a number is odd using bitwise operations. The last bit in a binary number is the ones place (or the 2^0 place). All odd numbers are going to have this bit turned on; it is what makes them odd. Therefore, by checking if a number has its last bit on (which is what `& 1` does), you are actually checking whether or not it is odd. Since it uses bitwise operations, it is considerably faster than using modulo 2 for this purpose.

Comment: @ouah Just expanded my answer :).

Answer (score 4):

Here, `&` is the [bitwise AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) operator.

`a&1` (or, rather `a & 1`) checks the LSB of `a` to be SET or not.